# Python, not understanding double quotes with nothing inside

Tags: python, security, syntax

got a bit of a noob question.

I'm trying to get Metagoofil working because it keeps saying "error downloading webpage" etc etc.

A google search found that I can change a bit of the code in one of the config files and it will work properly again.

I'm having a problem though: this seems to be the code I want to use.

```
self.url = url.replace("/url?q=", "", 1).split("&amp")[0]
```

BUT, it doesn't seem to like me (based on syntax highlighting) have those two quotation marks together with nothing in between. When they are like above, it starts highlighting `.split("` up to here thinking that this is the string.

My question is, how can I make the double quotations together without anything in the middle and have it register as its own string, so it doesn't highlight the `.split("`

Comment: Check the preceding lines for unmatched quotes and other syntax issues, and make sure you haven't somehow gotten curly quotes into your code.

Comment: Is it actually not working or are you just assuming it won't from the highlighting?

Comment: is one of the double quotes actually two single quotes?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem.

url = "/url?q=test"
print url
url = url.replace("/url?q=", "", 1).split("&amp")[0]
print url

Works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

The literal `""` is a valid string with a length of zero.  I guess your syntax highlighter is not working properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @G.Samaras Please explain how my answer is not explaining the cause of the problem! Thanks!

Comment: The OP ask how to make the double quotations together etc. . I do not see why you posted should be an answer and not a comment. I think it would be a brilliant comment, but not even a good answer.